# How to color code a SharePoint list date field based on comparison with todays date?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, date-field, color-field

I have a SharePoint list with a date column called 'Expiration Date' containing a date value.

Using some JS code, I would like to first check if the date value equals to today and if so I would like to highlight it in red.

Can someone help me with the JS code for the same.

**Node**: I am working with SPOnline.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**For Modern UI**:

Yes, you can use json formatting to conditionally color fields in sharepoint online.

The following example colors the current date field red when the value inside an item's ExpirationDate is before the current date/time.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$ExpirationDate] <= @now, '#ff0000', ''"
  }
}
```

Where `ExpirationDate` is the internal name of your SharePoint list column. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Source: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

**For Classic UI**:

You can use Client Side Rendering (CSR) which represents a rendering engine for list views, list forms and search results. I would recommend you to consider the following approach for your task.

Below example demonstrates how to highlight list rows based on their date values:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() { 

  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
    OnPostRender: function (ctx) {

        // get today's date
        var today = new Date();
        // zero out the time portion so we will only compare days
        today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

        var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

            // get the date set in your date YourDateField
            var itemDate = new Date(rows[i]['ExpirationDate']);
            // zero out the time portion so we only compare days
            itemDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

            var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
            var row = document.getElementById(rowId);

            if (itemDate >= today) {
                row.style.backgroundColor = '#ED9898';
            }
        }
    }
  });
});
```

For more clarification and how to add this code in JSLink of list view, see my answer [How to Highlight a Row on Active Status](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416).

Source:

1. [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. Does this work in Modern UI only? Should I use the internal name of Expiration Date field?

Comment: Yes. It works in Modern UI and use internal name of date field.

Comment: This will work only in Modern UI. for classic UI you need to use JSLink

Comment: @mdevm are you using modern UI or classic UI?

Comment: I am using CLassic UI

Comment: See updated answer. You can use client side rendering via JSLink in classic UI.

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others with same question to find the correct answer easily. It also removes the question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 2):

In Classic UI, we can add the following code into a script editor web part in list view to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () { 
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var fieldContext = {}; 
    fieldContext.Templates = {}; 
    fieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View 
        "Expiration_x0020_Date": { "View": fieldTemplate } 
    }; 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext);
})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function fieldTemplate(ctx) { 
    var expirationDate = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.ExpirationDate];
    // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value 
    if(new Date(expirationDate) <= new Date()) {
        return "<span style='color : red'>" + expirationDate + "</span>";
    }else {
        return expirationDate;
    }    
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use calculated columns or js link
See example in the link below

[Calculated Column to change text color in a custom list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118168/calculated-column-to-change-text-color-in-a-custom-list/118213)

Comment: Do not use calculated column as MS has removed this functionality from SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example I wanted to share here that applies to SharePoint 2013 on prem or it could be used in the classic experience in the new SharePoint. I stored my script in a site assets library and used the jslink to connect it to the list view. (Edit the page > edit the list web part > miscellaneous > JS Link: ~site/SiteAssets/ColorListDate.js)

Javascript:

```
(function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};

    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    //internal column name between double quotes on the next line. If your column name has a space in its internal name use "_x0020_" in place of the space. 
        "My_x0020_Date": {
            "View": ColorCodeDueDate
            }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function ColorCodeDueDate(ctx) {
    //update internal column name at the end of the next line
    var MyDateVar = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.My_x0020_Date);
    MyDateVar.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    var then1 = new Date();
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    then1.setDate(then1.getDate() + 1);

    var then3 = new Date();
    then3.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then3.setDate(then3.getDate() + 3);

    var then4 = new Date();
    then4.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then4.setDate(then4.getDate() + 4);

    // if there's no due date don't render anything. Also update the column names in the else statements below. If your column name has a space in its internal name use "_x0020_" in place of the space.
    if (MyDateVar < today) {
        return "<div style='background-color:red;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.My_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() == today.getTime()) { 
        return "<div style='background-color:orange;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.My_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() >= then1.getTime() && MyDateVar.getTime() <= then3.getTime()) { 
        return "<div style='background-color:yellow;color:black'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.My_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar >= then4) {  
        return "<div style='background-color:green;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.My_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
}
```

End result (today was 3/10/20 in my screen shot)

[image]

Sources that helped me

- This post :)
- This blog on Checking Date Equality in JavaScript:  http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/checking-date-equality-in-javascript.html