# Unable to highlight a row in yellow if a date column value is today's date

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am working with a SharePoint list that has a date & time type column called Change Window Start (internal name: Start_x0020_Time). I am using below code to highlight the item row and font color if change window start date is today but it is not working. 
Can someone help me correcting the code.

Again the data type is Date and time for change window start column.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() { 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function (ctx) {
            // get today's date
            var today = new Date();
            // zero out the time portion so we will only compare days
            today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                // get the date set in your date YourDateField
                var itemDate = new Date(rows[i]['Start_x0020_Time']);
                // zero out the time portion so we only compare days
                itemDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                if (row!=null&&itemDate === today) {                  
                    row.style.backgroundColor = 'red';  

                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried using both display name and internal name for Change window start but neither of that works.FYI, I am working with SPOnline.

Comment: This can be done using json formatting in modern experience. is there any other reason for using classic experience?

Comment: I have a calculated column based on change window start and change window end date & time column. When adding JSON code for a date column, it seems to affect the calculated column, odd but true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you need to use **internal name** while getting the date field. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

So, change

`var itemDate = new Date(rows[i]['Change Window Start']);`

to

`var itemDate = new Date(rows[i]['Start_x0020_Time']);`

And change condition in your `IF statement` as given below:

```
if (row!=null && itemDate == today)
```

**Update**:

Or You can also build the logic something like:

```
itemDate <= today.setHours(23,59,59) && itemDate >= today.setHours(0,0,0)
```

Comment: You can also build the logic something like, `itemDate < today.setHours(23,59,59) && itemDate > today.setHours(0,0,0) `. And if you want to use json formatting and modern experience then check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252371/how-to-color-code-a-sharepoint-list-date-field-based-on-comparison-with-todays-d/252380).

Comment: I updated the script in the question info, still no luck with it.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? Or wrong rows get colored? Or nothing happens at all?

Comment: Upon running the script on console, i see following message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <. However I don't see any additional '<' being used in the script.

Comment: One thing I am noticing is, the same script works for conditions: item date<=today or item date >= today but when it comes to equal to it does not work. So item date===today, item date==today  or item date = today does not work it seems. thoughts?

Comment: You should be getting line number where an error is. Also as I mentioned in first comment, you can use itemdate <= today(23:59:59) and itemdate >=today(0,0,0,).

Comment: Great thanks Ganesh, the sethours logic works. Can you update your answer so i can mark it as complete. Also one question, In addition to the background color, I also want to change the color of text from black to yellow or so. I tried row.style.color= 'green'; but that did not work, any thoughts?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please upvote and accept. And about changing color, it is bit difficult task as the rows contains `td`, `td` contains nested divs, spans, anchor tags and so on. And these elements inherits color properties from SharePoint default CSS.

Comment: So is there no way to highlight text color. I understand the complexity you mentioned but just wanted to know if that's possible by somehow thanks.

Comment: Maybe... By traversing all the child elements inside row and changing their color properties.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple errors found at a glance:

`new Date(rows[i]['Change Window Start']);` should use the internal column name.

`if (row!=null&&itemDate = today)` here you should use `===` like this: `if (row !== null && itemDate === today)`.

Best thing to do is to use the developer tools in the browser to debug the code and see where it goes wrong

Comment: Thanks Robert, used internal name and made the if condition change as well but still no luck, thoughts?

Comment: Robert it seems that comparison item date == today, item date===today and itemdate =today is not working. Althougth >= and <= works fine. Will euqal to comparison be more complicated since the column is of type date and time?Any thoughts?