# Calculated Column Assistance Needed

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have an expiration date column, and I need to mark the date red yellow green depending on:

if the exp date is within 30 days from today = red
if the exp date is within 60 to 90 from today = yellow
if the exp date is within 90+ from today = green

I know this basic formula but having a hard time getting much else to work:
="

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Is it classic experience or modern experience?

Comment: Check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252371/how-to-color-code-a-sharepoint-list-date-field-based-on-comparison-with-todays-d/252380#252380). This is for both classic UI & modern UI.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online, we can use [column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) to customize how fields in SharePoint lists and libraries are displayed.

Simple test for your reference:

@now+2592000000 means adding 30 days to today, @now+5184000000 means adding 60 days to today,@now+7776000000 means adding 90 days to today.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField>=@now&&@currentField<=@now+2592000000,'#FF4633',if(@currentField>=@now+5184000000&&@currentField<=@now+7776000000,'#F6FF33',if(@currentField>@now+7776000000,'#8DFF33','')"
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Please note that according to your description, it seems that 30 <expiration <60 is missed, and there will be no color change for the date between this timeline.