# Color Code SharePoint 2013 Column based on Date Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, json-formatting, jslink

I followed this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252371/how-to-color-code-a-sharepoint-list-date-field-based-on-comparison-with-todays-d) on this site about color coding a SharePoint Column based on a date column. This worked really well and I got the result I wanted.

I followed the answer from @chris-g. Below is my code:

```
    (function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    //internal column name between double quotes on the next line. If your column name has a space in its internal name use "_x0020_" in place of the space. 
        "Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date": {
            "View": ColorCodeNextReviewDate
            }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function ColorCodeNextReviewDate(ctx) {
    //update internal column name at the end of the next line
    var MyDateVar = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[2],ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[1]-1,ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[0]);
   
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    var then1 = new Date();
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    then1.setDate(then1.getDate() + 1);

    var then30 = new Date();
    then30.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then30.setDate(then30.getDate() + 30);

    var then31 = new Date();
    then31.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then31.setDate(then31.getDate() + 31);

    // if there's no due date don't render anything. Also update the column names in the else statements below. If your column name has a space in its internal name use "_x0020_" in place of the space.
    if (MyDateVar < today) {
        return "<div style='background-color:red;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() == today.getTime()) { 
        return "<div style='background-color:orange;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }   
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() >= then1.getTime() && MyDateVar.getTime() <= then30.getTime()) { 
        return "<div style='background-color:yellow;color:black'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar >= then31) {  
        return "<div style='background-color:#00a58e;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
}
```

I was hoping to also add DIV styles to the same IF statements to colour another column.  So currently, based off the formula, the "Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date" is coloured - I also want the "Next_x0020_Review" column (a calculated column) to be coloured.  So, I thought, I'd add the additional DIV lines to the result statements (which I think could work?) but I think my trouble area is in the initial Function statement at the top of the code where I add the column names (see below).  My expertise is not JS so I'm just trying and testing but no luck so far....  Any help would be most appreciated :-)

```
(function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    //internal column name between double quotes on the next line. If your column name has a space in its internal name use "_x0020_" in place of the space. 
        "Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date": {
            "View": ColorCodeNextReviewDate
            }
        "Next_x0020_Review": {
            "View": ColorCodeNextReviewDate
            }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function ColorCodeNextReviewDate(ctx) {
    //update internal column name at the end of the next line
    var MyDateVar = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[2],ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[1]-1,ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[0]);
   
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    var then1 = new Date();
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    then1.setDate(then1.getDate() + 1);

    var then30 = new Date();
    then30.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then30.setDate(then30.getDate() + 30);

    var then31 = new Date();
    then31.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then31.setDate(then31.getDate() + 31);

    // if there's no due date don't render anything. Also update the column names in the else statements below. If your column name has a space in its internal name use "_x0020_" in place of the space.
    if (MyDateVar < today) {
        return "<div style='background-color:red;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
        return "<div style='background-color:red;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() == today.getTime()) { 
        return "<div style='background-color:orange;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
        return "<div style='background-color:orange;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review + "</div>";
    }   
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() >= then1.getTime() && MyDateVar.getTime() <= then30.getTime()) { 
        return "<div style='background-color:yellow;color:black'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
        return "<div style='background-color:yellow;color:black'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar >= then31) {  
        return "<div style='background-color:#00a58e;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
        return "<div style='background-color:#00a58e;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review + "</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write separate handler functions for each column. Try using below code:

```
(function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        //internal column name between double quotes on the next line. If your column name has a space in its internal name use "_x0020_" in place of the space. 
        "Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date": {
            "View": ColorCodeNextReviewDate
        },
        "Next_x0020_Review": {
            "View": ColorCodeNextReviewColumn
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function ColorCodeNextReviewDate(ctx) {
    //update internal column name at the end of the next line
    var MyDateVar = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[2], ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[1] - 1, ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[0]);

    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    var then1 = new Date();
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    then1.setDate(then1.getDate() + 1);

    var then30 = new Date();
    then30.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then30.setDate(then30.getDate() + 30);

    var then31 = new Date();
    then31.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then31.setDate(then31.getDate() + 31);

    // if there's no due date don't render anything. Also update the column names in the else statements below. If your column name has a space in its internal name use "_x0020_" in place of the space.
    if (MyDateVar < today) {
        return "<div style='background-color:red;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() == today.getTime()) {
        return "<div style='background-color:orange;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() >= then1.getTime() && MyDateVar.getTime() <= then30.getTime()) {
        return "<div style='background-color:yellow;color:black'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar >= then31) {
        return "<div style='background-color:#00a58e;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date + "</div>";
    }
}

function ColorCodeNextReviewColumn(ctx) {
    //update internal column name at the end of the next line
    var MyDateVar = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[2], ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[1] - 1, ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review_x0020_Date.split('/')[0]);

    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    var then1 = new Date();
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    then1.setDate(then1.getDate() + 1);

    var then30 = new Date();
    then30.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then30.setDate(then30.getDate() + 30);

    var then31 = new Date();
    then31.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //use this to set how many days you want var then to be.
    then31.setDate(then31.getDate() + 31);

    // if there's no due date don't render anything. Also update the column names in the else statements below. If your column name has a space in its internal name use "_x0020_" in place of the space.
    if (MyDateVar < today) {
        return "<div style='background-color:red;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() == today.getTime()) {
        return "<div style='background-color:orange;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar.getTime() >= then1.getTime() && MyDateVar.getTime() <= then30.getTime()) {
        return "<div style='background-color:yellow;color:black'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review + "</div>";
    }
    else if (MyDateVar >= then31) {
        return "<div style='background-color:#00a58e;color:white'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Next_x0020_Review + "</div>";
    }
}
```

You can get the correct internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Nice one!  Worked perfectly.  Just in the event anyone else follows this, I also removed the second DIV elements from the first section of IF Statements.

Thanks Ganesh